# Calcular el tamaño de una lista enlazada

Tags: javascript

Enunciado

> Implementar el método size dentro del prototype de LinkedList que deberá retornar el tamaño actual de la LinkedList. En el caso de que la lista se encuentre vacía deberá retornar cero.

Ejemplo:

```
//    var lista = new LinkedList();
//    lista.size(); --> 0
//    lista.add(1);
//    lista.size(); --> 1
//    lista.add(2);
//    lista.add(3);
//    lista.size(); --> 3
```

este es mi código pero no me pasa el test, quisiera que me guien para saber en que me estoy equivocando.

```js
LinkedList.prototype.size = function(){

    this.size = 0;
    var nodoActual = this.head;

    if(nodoActual === null){
      return 0;
    }

    while ( nodoActual.next !== null){
      size++;
      nodoActual = nodoActual.next
    }
    return Linkedlist.size();
```

Comment: Te falta la llave de cierre de la función `}`

Comment: podrias agregar el metodo add cambien?

Comment: Creo que deberías devolver `this.size` y, de hecho, dentro del ciclo, actualizar la propiedad y no simplemente la variable `size` que ni siquiera has definido previamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LinkedList.prototype.size = function () {
   this.size = 0;
   var nodoActual = this.head;
   while (nodoActual) {
      this.size++;
      nodoActual = nodoActual.next;
   }
   return this.size;
}
```

Se agregan los valores:

```
var lista = new LinkedList();
lista.add(1);
lista.add(2);
lista.add(3);
lista.add(50);
lista.add(20);
lista.add(520);
```

Se muestra en consola:

```
console.log(lista.size());
```

El resultado en este caso es 6

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que verificar primero que el nodo actual no sea null, si esto se cumple ya sabes que por lo menos tenes un nodo, ahi tendrias que declarar size = 1. Si no siempre te va a contar uno menos. Y retorna size.

```
LinkedList.prototype.size = function(){
var nodoActual = this.head;
if(nodoActual === null){
  return 0;
}
var size = 1;
while ( nodoActual.next !== null){
  size++;
  nodoActual = nodoActual.next
}
return size;
```